# Logstash and Elasticsearch config

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

In my logstash yml i have configured output as below

```
output {
 elasticsearch {
  hosts => ["<another_host_ip>"]
  manage_template => false
  index => "my-index"
 }
}
```

And Elastic search was running in another host. I am able to get response from elastic search by doing cURL as

> curl -I http://localhost:9200

But Logstash was not able to connect to the Elastic server running in another host.

### Error log

```
[logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://<another_host_ip>:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://<another_host_ip>:9200/][Manticore::SocketException] Connection refused"}
```

What can be wrong? Your help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have X-Pack installed?

Comment: @MichaelDz You don't need X-Pack to work with logstash.

Comment: @MuhammadZubairSaleem I know, but sometimes X-Pack causes this kind of problems.

Comment: do `curl -l <another_host_ip>:9200`, problem seems ES is not running on another host.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single quotes around your host array like ip:port pair.

**Example**

```
output {
        elasticsearch {
          hosts => ['<ip>:<port>',
                    '<ip>:<port>']
          index => "logstash-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
          document_type => "log"
        }
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
      }
```

I hope this will sort your issue.

Comment: I always use double quotes and it works fine. Single quotes should be used when string contains double quotes.

Comment: That can be the case But in my case, I got issues using Double Quotes and Single Quotes Fixes those.